# Owin use external forms authentication cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

So I think my issue is going to be that I have one MVC website using standard forms authentication and one MVC which is geared more towards ASP.NET Identity.

What I am trying to do is configure my Owin Authentication to read and accept the auth cookie generated by the standard MVC forms auth site. Everything is configured as below but I just can't seem to get Owin to accept the cookie.

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    CookieHttpOnly = true,
    CookieName = "myAuthCookie",
    CookieDomain = ".mydomain.com",
    CookiePath = "/",
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is not possible. Cookie authentication middleware is claims-based and serializes all the claims associated with the identity into the authentication ticket in the cookie. Forms authentication stores the user name and some additional data but it knows nothing about the claims. Basically, the authentication ticket which is put inside the cookie is completely different in both the cases and you will not be able to get the cookie authentication middleware read the ticket created by FAM or vice versa.